# How JSON deserialize datetime and convert from UTC to a specified time zone?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, timezone, jsonserializer

I want to create a custom json serializer that will convert objects with dateTime to and from UTC and back to a specified time zone. (Not local)

Example which converts to UTC is:

```
MyObject stuff = new MyObject();
stuff.Date = DateTime.Now;

string asdd = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stuff,
            new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
            });
```

How do I convert from UTC back to a specific timezone via JsonSerializerSettings or a custom serializer?

Note: I'm working in .NET Core 2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time zone conversion should not be handled at time of serialization or deserialization.  Those are separate concerns.

Instead:

Leave `DateTimeZoneHandling` at its default of `RoundtripKind`. (Don't set it to `Utc`.) 
 This has the behavior of:

- If you are deserializing to a `DateTime`, and passing no offset in your data, then `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` will be set.
- If you are deserializing to a `DateTime`, and passing a trailing `Z` in your data, then `DateTimeKind.Utc` will be set.
- If you are deserializing to a `DateTime`, and passing an offset in your data, then `DateTimeKind.Local will be set, and the value will be converted to the local time zone (generally one should avoid this).
- If you are deserializing to a `DateTimeOffset`, then the offset will be persisted and the value will not change (this is the better approach if passing offsets).

Once you have a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` value, then use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` and similar methods to change time zones if necessary.  This part should be in your application code, as it tends to be specific to the logic of a particular API.

Generally speaking, it's an antipattern ([SRP violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) to try to treat all incoming or outgoing date/time data to be in the same time zone, whether via serialization or some other mechanism.