# How to find all DateTime properties of anonymous object?

Tags: c#, reflection, timezone, utc, propertyinfo

I want to convert all dates received from client into UTC before processing them in server side code. I am thinking to use ActionFilter where I want to find all the date fields from Request payload and convert those into UTC dates. I know Reflection helps in finding properties by it's type but it doesn't work in case of Anonymous objects.

Below is my code sample

```
        //convert body to object
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(rawRequest);
        var type = result.GetType();

        //get collection of properties from object
        var properties = result.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            //if data type is DateTime then convert into UTC
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?) || property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                string TimeZoneId = "India Standard Time";
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["TimeZoneId"] != null)
                {
                    TimeZoneId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.GetValues("TimeZoneId").FirstOrDefault();
                }
                var localTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneId);
                var Date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(((DateTime?)property.GetValue(result, null)) ?? DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
                var localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(Date, localTimeZone);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi.  Please edit your question to include the code *as text* - not as a picture of your code.  Please also read: [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the Stack Overflow help center.  Thank you.

Comment: Also, in general - the idea of trying to convert all of your values from a specific time zone to UTC arbitrarily is not advised.  It can lead to later issues such as when some new part of your application needs to take input in UTC or in some other time zone.  See my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51618873/634824

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, Thanks. I have edited my question statement to include code as text. Please suggest the best way to handle the scenario where we want to show date in user's timezone. I did some research and it's advised to save dates in UTC and convert into user's timezone while presentation. I want to do it for my existing app so want to handle globally and generically without making changes in every class or file.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be Java. Which language it is? You should always tag the corresponding language when you post a question.